# Setting alerts for review on images and documents in moss

Tags: alert, document, 2007

In Moss we can set an alert on a publishing page to review the content. Does anybody know how this can this be done with images and documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you mean here, but in short you can enable the following on all items in SharePoint:

- alerts
- content approval
- approval workflow

These are the things relevant to this conversation I think, but lots of other behaviours (e.g. versioning) can also be applied to every item type.

Or did you mean a retention policy i.e. to be alerted after a certain period to perhaps check the data is still current?

Comment: I meant retention policy then I guess. In a publishing site when creating a wcm page it's possible to set a date to be alerted to review - I'm looking for a way to do this with document and image lists. thx

Answer (score 0):

For a retention policy, have you tried looking at the "Information management policy settings" page on the document library or picture library?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101733771033.aspx